# After deleting all my cookies I'm still logged in my google account

Tags: firefox, security

I'm using firefox in private navigation. I connect into my google account then I delete all my cookies and then I'm still connected into google.

1. Why is this so ?
2. If I delete my cookies and disconnect manually from my google
   account does it still know it's me thank to the files that kept me connected ?
3. Is there an addon to adress this security problem ?

EDIT : when I disconnect from my account, then I delete all my cookies, then I try to reconnect into my google account, google still knows it's me because it's pre-entering my mail and asks only for my password.

Comment: Firefox should nuke everything relating to the inPrivate session once you close out of Firefox completely.  Does this occur even after closing/reopening the entire program?

Comment: no when I start the sesssion again I am disconnected from google of course. Everything I asked was without restarting the private session.

Comment: Did you clear saved passwords in Firefox? If you have it saved for Google, Firefox will log you in automatically.

Comment: If you were still logged in when you deleted your cookies you are still in a session regardless of the cookies being there or not but logging out and then deleting your cookies should stop it remembering you, although being in private should prevent any web applications from remembering your login details anyway

Comment: -CharlieRB : I'm not using the password saver at all. 
-Nathan Taylor : Well yes I'm still connected when I delete my cookies, then I refresh google and I'm still connected. If I proceed like you say I don't even need to delete my cookies it will keep me disconnected. I am willing to understand what on my computed is keeping me connected after I delete all the cookies.